# Как передать методом post ответы на вопросы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Вообщем друзья помогите есть такой вот код:

```
    $(function(){$('.contactform1')
           .submit(function(){if($(this).validationEngine('validate'))
 {$(this).ajaxSubmit();gtag('event','request',


  {'event_category':'request','event_action':'request'});
 $(this).clearForm();$
  .arcticmodal('close');
`введите сюда код`  $(".thanks").arcticmodal();}return 
 false;});$.each($('.minconf span.textbtn'),function(index,val)
 {$(val).text($(val).closest('form')

           .find('button, 
            input[type="submit"]').text());});$('.contactform_q')
           .submit(function(){if($(this).validationEngine('validate'))
         {$('.contactform_q input[name="quiz"]').val('вопрос1 '+q1+'. 
   вопрос2: '+q2+'. вопрос3: '+q3+'. вопрос4: '+q4+'; вопрос5: 
   '+q5+'.'+'Сумма: '+$('.fades7 
   .counternew').text());$(this).ajaxSubmit();gtag('event','request',
   {'event_category':'request','event_action':'request'});

  $(this).clearForm();$.arcticmodal('close');

   $(".thanks2").arcticmodal();}return
   false;});if(navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)){var 
   msViewportStyle=document.createElement('style')
   msViewportStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode('@-ms-
   viewport{width:auto!important}'))
   document.querySelector('head').appendChild(msViewportStyle)}

   var q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6;
    $(".callback_next").on("click",function(){$('.basic').fadeOut(0);
    $('.row .width').fadeOut(0);
    $('.nextblock').fadeIn(300);$('.fadesxs3').fadeIn(300);function 
    printNumbersInterval(){var i=300;var timerId=setInterval(function()
    {var i2=i/10;
    $('.discount-total-count').text(i2.toFixed(1)+"%");if(i==0)
    {clearInterval(timerId);}i=i-1;function func(){$('.discount-total-
    count').removeClass('animated flash');}setTimeout(func,500);function 
    func2(){$('.discount-total-count').addClass('animated 
    flash');}setTimeout(func2,1000);},1000);}printNumbersInterval();});
    $('.fades3 .answers label,.fades4 .answers label,.fades5 .answers 
    label')
    .click(function(event){if($(this).find('.checkin').html()=='')
     {$(this)
    .find('.checkin').html('<i class="fa fa-check">');}else{$(this)
     .find('.checkin').html('');}$(this).closest('.block')

   .find('button.mybtn_white').fadeIn(300).addClass('blockbtn');});
   $('.fades2 
         .answers label,.fades6 .answers label')
   .click(function(event){if($(this)
   .find('.checkin').html()==''){$(this).closest('.answers')
            .find('.checkin').html('');$(this)
            .find('.checkin').html('<i class="fa fa-
   check">');}else{$(this)
            .find('.checkin').html('');$(this).closest('.block')



  .find('button.mybtn_white').fadeOut(300).removeClass('blockbtn');}
 $(this).clo
                 sest('.block')

 .find('button.mybtn_white').fadeIn(300).addClass('blockbtn');});var 
 f1,f2,f3,f4;f2=0;f3=0;f4=0;$(".nexts2").on("click",function()
 {$('.fades2').fadeOut(0);$('.fades3').fadeIn(300);q1=$('.fades2')
            .find('i.fa.fa-check').closest('.div').data('s');

            $('input[name=step1]').val(q1);});
   $(".nexts3").on("click",function(){$('.fades3').fadeOut(0);
   $('.fades4').fadeIn(300);$.each($('.fades3 i.fa.fa-
   check'),function(index,val){q2=$(val).closest('.div').data('s')+'. 
   '+q2;});
    q2=q2.split('undefined');q2=q2[0];


            $('input[name=step2]').val(q2);});
      $(".nexts4").on("click",function(){$('.fades4').fadeOut(0);
     $('.fades5').fadeIn(300);$.each($('.fades4 i.fa.fa-
   check'),function(index,val){q3=$(val).closest('.div').data('s')+'. 
'+q3;});
 q3=q3.split('undefined');q3=q3[0];
            $('input[name=step3]').val(q3);});
  $(".nexts5").on("click",function(){$('.fades5').fadeOut(0);
 $('.fades6').fadeIn(300);$.each($('.fades5 i.fa.fa-
check'),function(index,val){q4=$(val).closest('.div').data('s')+'. 
'+q4;});
 q4=q4.split('undefined');q4=q4[0];
            $('input[name=step4]').val(q4);});var summas;
 $(".nexts6").on("click",function(){$('.fades6').fadeOut(0);
 $('.fadesxs3').fadeOut(0);$('.fades7').fadeIn(300);
 $('.fades7 .counternew').text($('.discount-total-count').text());
 q5=$('.fades6')
 .find('i.fa.fa-check').closest('.div').data('s');
            $('input[name=step5]').val(q5);
            $('input[name=discount]').val($('.discount-total-
 count').text());});});
```

он записывает ответы на вопросы в `<input name=step>`
 Как сделать, чтоб он не передавал эти ответы в `input` а передал их `post` на `index2.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала берём значения из `<input id="step">` в переменную

```
var value_step = document.getElementById('step').value;
```

Для передачи данных методом пост с помощью AJAX убедитесь что вы посылаете правильный заголовок например

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Далее передаём это значение на сервер вот так

```
httpRequest.send('value_step='+value_step);  // передаем данные на сервер
```

Где 'value_step' будет ключ для получения на стороне сервера.

Т.е. на сервере вы принимаете `$_POST['value_step']; //здесь будет переданное значение`